# Can't connect to TCP/IP printer with undescore "_" in the IP

Tags: wifi, printing, network, tcp

I have a wireless printer that's connected to our private LAN in our workplace. There is a weird configuration for the printer that it requires two printers to be added. For color - 192.168.51.xxx and one for grayscale - 192.168.51.xxx_1 <---
There's a problem on MacOS that says it cannot connect to a printer with that IP but on windows it runs completely fine. The company previously worked with another IT company and they got it set up on one macbook in the entire workplace, but I cannot replicate the steps that they've taken. Maybe there's other ways to add a printer, besides the regular control panel?

I've only seen posts about ports, but not with this kind of IP as it's unusual.

The printer model is - Konica Minolta INEO+ 220

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> underscore “_” in the IP

IP address does not contain an underscore.

Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing

192.168.51.xxx_1 is the Port Name, not the IP address of your printer, port name is auto-generated and "_#" is added to avoid duplicates names. So if you are using 192.168.51.xxx_1 to connect to the printer it will not work as this is not the IP address of your printer.

Comment: Well, then why does it work on windows but not on Mac? We have 2 devices that have 2 versions of printing and both include underscores in the IP.

Comment: There is no such thing as an IP address with an underscore. If Windows manages to connect then it must be ignoring or failing to parse it rather than making you correct it.

Comment: @HenrijsS check this answer https://superuser.com/a/1002863

Comment: I added a photo to the post, because can't add it to a comment. I'm telling you that the printer with this IP works completely differently and accepts other configurations. The default one doesn't allow to change color on Mac. The option just isn't there. And, if I add the printer again, after adding the default one, windows automatically adds the "_1" at the end of the IP, but in this one , it's the port name. I'll try to get a photo of these printers on a mac.

Comment: you have underscore in the port name, not the IP address. I suspect the printer is simply at a different IP address, regardless of what the port name says. Simply check on the printer itself for the ip address and use that

Answer (score 0):

The printer will only have one IP address, and this cannot include an underscore, as commented.

1. Check that you actually have the correct IP address for the printer. You can often print out a status report or get the IP on the printer's control panel. Check that the Mac is on the same subnet.
2. Have you installed any drivers for it?
3. You really need to find and read the documentation for the printer. If it can split colour and greyscale into separate logical paths, then this is likely to be done by print queues.